# Construction Quote Log

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm reworking my company's log of the proposals we send out, trying to indicate the total dollars that we could conceivably be awarded.

The challenge I'm having goes something like this:
We are a vendor and bid our product to installers that are themselves bidding on construction projects.
In a given month there may be ten projects where we offer pricing to say five installers.
Ten projects with five installers each = 50 quotes  -  but still there's only 10 quotes (projects) that we could conceivably be awarded.

Additionally, commonly each project can go through something like two revisions before it's awarded.
This means that we end up sending 100 quotes - but still there's only the ten projects we could conceivably be awarded.

How can I derive the total of just the potentially awardable projects?

Is there a way to indicate only the latest awardable dollar revision of a quoted project in an "Awardable $" column?

A simplified version of what I'm hoping to accomplish looks like this:

[image: SO25210139 question example]

Comment: This is more of a business problem that a technical one. What's the business's definition of how to calculate "latest awardable dollar revision of a quoted project"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about what the business means by awardable-value

Comment: Perhaps more simply put: I want the "Amount Quoted" value per row  to appear in the "Awardable $" cell in same row. However I only want one value per each unique four digit prefixed "Quote #". And I only want the value that has the highest numerical value of the "Rx" suffix if it has one. pnuts - This will be in a table that is sortable, so the Rx revisions may not always be below the previous revisions. There will be a column for recording quoted date, and I will be able to sort by Job Name.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your first question:

In your attached example cell E12 is simply the summation of cells E2:E11 and will automatically update based on the changes you make to the cells within the E2:E11 range.

In Excel, go to the cell you want the totals to appear -> find your sum formula -> click it -> select the cell ranges you want to total up -> done.

To answer your second question:

I can't :)  I could take a stab if you provide more info.

Comment: @pnuts you could be right, but I can't put it together based on what they have asked.